# For each ideal $I$ of $B$, there seems to be a corresponding morphism $f/I :A/f^{-1}I \rightarrow B/I$. Is this right?

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification

(All my rings are commutative with $1$.)

Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a morphism of rings. Then for each ideal $I$ of $B$, there seems to be a corresponding morphism $$f/I :A/f^{-1}I \rightarrow B/I$$ given by: $$(f/I)(a+f^{-1} I) = f(a)+I$$

Furthermore, if I'm not mistaken, $f/I$ should always be injective.

> **Question.** Is this right? If so, can someone just check my proofs, that I'm not fooling myself? If not, I'd like to see a counterexample.

*Well-definedness.*

Suppose $a + f^{-1}I = a'+f^{-1}I.$ We're trying to show $f(a)+I = f(a')+I$.

From $a + f^{-1}I = a'+f^{-1}I,$ deduce $f(a + f^{-1}I) = f(a'+f^{-1}I).$

This implies $$f(a)+ff^{-1}I = f(a')+ff^{-1}I$$

Hence $$f(a)+(f(A) \cap I) = f(a') + (f(A)\cap I)$$

So adding $I$ to both sides, we deduce $$f(a)+I = f(a') + I,$$ as required.

*Injectivity.*

Suppose $(f/I)(a+f^{-1}I) = I$. We need to show that $a+f^{-1}I = f^{-1}I$.

Then:

$$f(a)+I = I.$$

Hence $$f^{-1}(f(a)+I) = f^{-1}(I).$$ So $$f^{-1}f(a)+f^{-1}I = f^{-1}I.$$

So $$a+\mathrm{ker}(f)+f^{-1}I = f^{-1}I$$

Hence $$a+f^{-1}I = f^{-1}I,$$ as required.

Comment: for example against the assumption that $f (a + f^{-1} (I)) = I$
is not always true : take the morphism $n \mapsto 2n$ from $A=Z$
to $Z/12Z$ and the ideal $I=3Z/12Z$, then $f^{-1} (I) = 3Z $ and
$f(f^{-1}(I))=6Z/12Z$  while $f (a) + 6Z/12Z\neq 3Z/12Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first proof is correct, albeit long. The second proof has a flaw for me: you implicitly suppose
$$f^{-1}(I+J)=f^{-1}(I)+f^{-1}(J) $$
which is false in  general, unless $f$ is an isomorphism. We only have $\;
f^{-1}(I)+f^{-1}(J)\subseteq f^{-1}(I+J)$.
It is false even if $f$ is injective. As a counter-example, consider the canonical injection of a field $F$ into $F[X]$, and two coprime ideals of $F[X]$. The $I+J=F[X]$, so $f^{-1}(I+J)=F$, while $f^{-1}(I)=f^{-1}(J)=0$.

I would make the proofs shorter this way:

- *Well-definedness*
  \begin{align*}a+ f^{-1}(I) = a'+f^{-1}(I)&\iff a-a'\in f^{-1}(I)\iff f(a)-f(a')\in I\\&\iff f(a)\in f(a')+I\iff a+f(I)\subseteq a'+f(I).
  \end{align*}
  By symmetry, we also have the reverse inclusion, therefore equality.
- *injectivity*
  If $f(a)+I=I$, we have $f(a)\in I$, so $a\in f^{-1}(I)$, and finally $a+ f^{-1}(I)=f^{-1}(I)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on your problem. It doesn't answer your question, but I hope that it will help you to see another way of thinking about it. It is also too long for a comment.

First off, if you have a homomorphism $g:A\to C$, then there is always a corresponding homomorphism $g':A/\ker g \to C$ such that $g = g'\circ \phi$ (where $\phi:A \to A/\ker g$ is the canonical map). $g'$ is injective for the following reason:

> Take an element in the kernel of $g'$. That element may be written as $\phi(a)$ for some $a \in A$. Since it's in the kernel of $g'$, we know that $g'(\phi(a)) = 0$. But $g'\circ \phi = g$, so we also have $g(a) = 0$. Therefore $a \in \ker g$, so $\phi(a) = 0$.

That out of the way, let's take a look at your situation. Let $\phi:B \to B/I$ is the canonical quotient map. The above discussion (using $C = B/I$ and $g = \ker(\phi \circ f)$) gives us the commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A @>f>>B\\
@V\psi VV @VV\phi V\\
A/\ker(\phi\circ f)@>f'>> B/I
\end{CD}
$$in which $f'$ (which is what you called $f/I$) is indeed injective.

I personally think that this is a better way to view the problem. Inverse images of ideals have their uses, but I find it more intuitive to think about $f^{-1}I$ as the kernel of the composite map $A\to B \to B/I$ than as the concrete, inverse image of elements in $I$. Note that a lot of our machinery for rings considers when an element is (or is sent to) zero, and more or less any theorem that instead considers it contained in some ideal will at some point divide out by that ideal and reason with $0$ instead.